# How to add static method in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

Could any one please tell how to add static method in the WCF service. I am getting an error if i use a static method in the interface of WCF service.

Comment: please provide more detail. Why does it need to be static?  Where are you calling it from?  What's the method's purpose?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a static method in a WCF Service.

A static method or member is a member of a class, so you need to have direct access (please understand access as a reference) to your class to do it. In the case of a service, you're not accessing your class, but a proxy object that knows how to call your methods and the types they return. So all methods that will be called via WCF must be a OperationContract from a ServiceContract decorated class or interface.

If you want a service with only one instance, you have to decorate your service class with a ServiceBehavior attribute and set the InstanceContextMode to single.

Answer (score 2):

It seems static methods are not supported for WCF service, because .NET interfaces can not contain static methods.

How about [Singleton Service](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Queued-Services/Instance-Management/)?